# How to register per request dependencies using StructureMap, MVC 5, and WebApi 2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2, structuremap

I have a Mvc5-WebApi2 application that uses StructureMap for dependency injection using the StructureMap.Mvc5 and StructureMap.WebApi2 Nuget packages. I want to register my EF 6 DbContext with HttpContext lifecycle for both MVC and Web controllers. Can someone point me to a succinct explanation on how to achieve this for both MVC and WebApi? In general, how can I register certain dependencies in a per request container and others in the parent container?

Comment: If you have access to Pluralsight, there's a section on StructureMap and EF in this great video: http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/build-application-framework-aspdotnet-mvc-5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The recommended approach to `HttpContext` bound life-cycles is to harness StructureMap's [nested containers](http://structuremap.github.io/the-container/nested-containers/).

This works by configuring a StructureMap container and then creating a nested instance of the container and storing it in the `HttpContext` at the start of the request and using that container throughout the HttpRequest before disposing of it at the end ([see here for the source code](https://github.com/webadvanced/Structuremap.MVC5/blob/master/content/DependencyResolution/StructureMapDependencyScope.cs.pp)).

You can set this up yourself ([see this blog post on how to do this](http://www.khalidabuhakmeh.com/utilizing-structuremap-3-with-asp-net-mvc)) or you can use both of these NuGet packages to do it for you:

[StructureMap.MVC5](https://www.nuget.org/packages/StructureMap.MVC5/) and [StructureMap.WebApi](https://www.nuget.org/packages/StructureMap.WebApi2/).

Once set up you can then register your 
`DbContext` in the normal fashion:

```
this.For<DbContext>.Use(new DbContext(connectionString));
```

I hope this helps. If you do have any questions then I'll try my best to help.

Comment: Yup, I learned this on my own by adding debug statements to my context, but the docs really could be more explicit. The short answer is both these Nuget packages create everything in a per request container, so even your auto-wired dependencies get disposed of. Part of my question comes from the fact that the MVC5 package says it doesn't work for WebApi, so I was unsure whether they shared the same containers/dependencies. 

They do. Yay. All good.

Comment: Thanks @JosephWoodward! now i get it! i was so confused about this new way of thinking used to the old school structuremap, this post cleared my mind.